# Java - Why void when I'm storing value in variable

Tags: java, void

So, the question is. If I'm calling method guess from class - `Player` and it is a  void-type method without return statement in it, how come I'm able to store result of `number = (int)(Math.random() * 10)` in `number` variable for 3 different objects `(p1, p2, p3)`?

I'm little confused about when should I use return statement or void-type methods, because if `number = (int)(Math.random() * 10)` is giving some results which I want to use, why then I don't need to return this results from a method to pass them to the `number` variable which I declared in `int number = 0;`

```
    public class Player {
       int number = 0;

       public void guess() {
          number = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
          System.out.println("I'm guessing " + number);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `void` method does not return anything, but it still allows you to do things. (Print to the console, modify variables etc) The `void` keyword just means that it doesn't return a value. (In `void` methods you can still use a blank `return;` to end the method) And because you are modifying your `number` variable in the `GuessGame` object the changes you make will stay even though you don't return a variable. Try this simple test to see what I mean:

```
//In your GuessGame class
int number = 0;
public void foo() {
    number++;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GuessGames games = new GuessGames();
    games.foo();
    System.out.println(games.number);
    //Outputs 1
}
```

---

[docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) for the `return` statement

Answer (score 1):

The point is: where is the result of `Math.random() * 10` *physically* stored on your computer when your program is run? You list two options.

**Options 1: Instance field**

In this case the compiler instructs your operating system to reserve space for a `int` variable for the whole life of the `Player` object. The player object may live for microseconds, seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, ... it depends! This storage space is usually find in the RAM of the computer and from Java you can access it with the syntax `myPlayer.number` as long as you have a Player reference somewhere.

**Options 2: Return value**

In this case the compiler finds the space to store the result of the computation in a register of the Java virtual machine, that you can mentally map to a register of the physical processor. This value will only at best survive for a couple of processor cycles (there are gazillinos in a GHz CPU, so it's really a tiny little fracion of a second) if you don't store it somewhere else - and if you don't it's lost **forever**. See the following example:

```
private int someRandom;

private int gimmeARandom() {
  return Math.random() * 10;
}

private int test() {
  int someRandom = gimmeARandom(); // --> store the value until end of method
  this.someRandom = someRandom;    // --> further keep it so we can read it later
  gimmeARandom();                  // --> what did it returned? We'll never know
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Void is different than static - `void` just means the function does not return anything, but it can still be a instance method, i.e. one that is associated with each `new` instance of a class. I think you're confusing this with the functionality of `static`, which allows methods to be called without an instance of the class.